# compare sonarQube Metrics with a String in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sonarqube, metrics

I use SonarQube to create my own language plugin. I have created a widget that recover a simple String ("tutu").
I display in the widget the String with : `<%= format_measure('sonar.metric.arcadsoftware.rpg.ruleset1') -%>` and the result is well 'tutu'.

But I have the following problem :

I want to create a function that compare the string value with another string but I don't succeed to compare the both String.

My function is : (var = 'tutu')

```
<%
def test_variable(codechecker_metric_result)

var = format_measure(codechecker_metric_result)

if var == "tutu"
  var = "tata"
end

var
```

end
%>

The result of the function is "tutu" or it should be "tata".

So if you can help me to resolve it issue.

Thank

M.KOZA

Answer (score 0):

I try a solution at my problem, if that can help another people.
I use the function .include("").
For example :  `var.include("tutu")`